# ViewComponent call with configuration-object

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

This is my first question, so please have mercy!

I am trying to Invoke the following ViewComponent:

```
public IViewComponentResult Invoke(MyConfiguration config)
{
    return View(config);
}
```

My calling code looks like this:

```
@(await Component.InvokeAsync<MyViewComponent>(new MyConfiguration () { color: "red" }))
```

The ViewComponent get called, but config is null. Is anyone knowing what I have to change for it to work?

Note: I tried the code below, which worked. But creating an anonymous wrapper object seems ugly.

```
@(await Component.InvokeAsync<MyViewComponent>(new { config = new MyConfiguration () { color: "red" }}))
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm always using such syntax and have no problems with that:

```
@await Component.InvokeAsync("MyViewComponent", new { aaa = "aaa", bbb = "bbb" })
```

or

```
@await Component.InvokeAsync("MyViewComponent", new { config = new MyConfiguration () { color: "red" }})
```

or

```
@await Component.InvokeAsync("MyViewComponent", Model.Config)
```